# difference in two table without key column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have two table which don't have a key and I need to concatenate all column than need to check three condition, because table missing key column.

- If record in one present in other without any change then in custom column  "No Change"
- If  record present in table 'old' but not present in table new then in custom column "Record deleted"
- If  record present in table 'new' but not present in table old then in custom column " New Record "

---

```
Declare @old table
(

BaseVehicle   VARCHAR (50),
BaseVehicleID VARCHAR (50),
Years         VARCHAR (50),
Make          VARCHAR (50),
MakeID        VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT @old
SELECT  '2002 Freightliner FL60',   '127640',           '2002',         'Freightliner', '497'  UNION ALL
SELECT '2002 Freightliner FL70',    '127641',           '2002',         'Freightliner', '497'  UNION ALL
SELECT  '2014 Check',   '127979',               '2014',         'BMW',  '31'  UNION ALL-- Record Deleted
SELECT  '2003 Freightliner FL50',   '127655',           '2003',         'Freightliner', '497'  UNION ALL
SELECT  '2003 check',   'test',         '2003',         'Freightliner', '497'  UNION ALL-- Record Deleted
SELECT  '2003 Freightliner FL70',   '127657',           '2003',         'Freightliner', '497' 

Declare @new table

(


BaseVehicle    VARCHAR (50),
BaseVehicleID  VARCHAR (50),
Years          VARCHAR (50),
Make           VARCHAR (50),
MakeID         VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT @new
SELECT  '2014 Jeep Cherokee',   '127768',               '2014',         'Jeep', '42' UNION ALL-- New Records
SELECT  '2011 Ford E-250'    ,    '96774',              '2011',         'Ford', '54'  UNION ALL-- New Records
SELECT  '2014 BMW Alpina B7L',  '127979',               '2014',         'BMW',  '31'  UNION ALL-- New Records
SELECT  '2002 Freightliner FL60',   '127640',           '2002',         'Freightliner', '497'  UNION ALL -- No Changes
SELECT  '2002 Freightliner FL70',   '127641',           '2002',         'Freightliner', '497'  UNION ALL--  No Changes
SELECT  '2003 Freightliner FL50',   '127655',           '2003',         'Freightliner', '497'  UNION ALL--  No Changes
SELECT  '2003 Freightliner FL70',   '127657',           '2003',         'Freightliner', '497' --  No Changes
```

and Output should look like

```
BaseVehicle,    BaseVehicleID,  Years,  Make,        MakeID  ,Message

2014 Check,     127979,         2014,   BMW,          31,    Deleted Row
2003 check,     test,           2003,   Freightliner, 497,   Deleted Row
'2014 Jeep Cherokee',   '127768','2014','Jeep', '42' ,       New Records
'2011 Ford E-250'    ,    '96774','2011','Ford',    '54' ,  New Records
'2014 BMW Alpina B7L',  '127979', '2014','BMW', '31',       New Records
'2002 Freightliner FL60',   '127640','2002','Freightliner', '497' , No Changes
'2002 Freightliner FL70',   '127641','2002','Freightliner', '497',   No Changes
'2003 Freightliner FL50',   '127655','2003','Freightliner', '497' ,  No Changes
'2003 Freightliner FL70',   '127657','2003','Freightliner', '497' ,  No Changes
```

Comment: i am using sql-server-2008

Comment: Instead of concat use SET operations ..intersect , minus etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 computed columns to your tables

```
Declare @old table
(
BaseVehicle   VARCHAR (50),
BaseVehicleID VARCHAR (50),
Years         VARCHAR (50),
Make          VARCHAR (50),
MakeID        VARCHAR (50)
OldRow AS (BaseVehicle+BaseCehicleID+Years+Make+MakeID)
)

Declare @new table
(
BaseVehicle    VARCHAR (50),
BaseVehicleID  VARCHAR (50),
Years          VARCHAR (50),
Make           VARCHAR (50),
MakeID         VARCHAR (50)
NewRow AS (BaseVehicle+BaseCehicleID+Years+Make+MakeID)
)
```

Then use this query

```
SELECT 
    Old.BaseVehicle
    ,Old.BaseVehicleID
    ,Old.Years
    ,Old.Make
    ,Old.MakeID
    ,CASE WHEN New.OldRow IS NULL THEN 'Record Deleted' ELSE 'No Change' END AS NewColumn
FROM @Old Old
LEFT OUTER JOIN @New New ON Old.OldRow = New.NewRow
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    New.BaseVehicle
    ,New.BaseVehicleID
    ,New.Years
    ,New.Make
    ,New.MakeID
    ,'Record Added' AS NewColumn
FROM @New New
LEFT OUTER JOIN @Old Old ON New.NewRow = Old.OldRow
WHERE Old.OldRow IS NULL
```

Comment: did you modify the table variable definitions as explained?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID,'NO CHANGES'
from
(
select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID
from
@Old
intersect
select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID
from
@new)NO_CHANGE_TABLE
UNION ALL
Select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID,'RECORD DELETED'
from
(
select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID
from
@OLD
EXCEPT
select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID
from
@new)RECORD_DELETED_TABLE
UNION ALL
Select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID,'NEW RECORD'
from
(
select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID
from
@new
EXCEPT
select BaseVehicle,BaseVehicleID,Years,Make,MakeID
from
@old)NEW_RECORD_TABLE
```

Comment: interesting, but all  `INTERSECT` return same rows

Comment: Thanks anwaar: but i am looking for only deleted records from old table and No Changes record and new records from new table in the output

Comment: @Shan i pasted wrong query...last two intersect should be minus or more specifically EXCEPT in SQL server.

Comment: @Shan Welcome ..if it also gives you expected output you can press the upward button...:)